# Echoing an array containing elements with spaces as an argument to another command

Tags: arrays, bash, macos, echo

I am writing a little script that outputs a list of duplicate files in the directory, ie. pairs of `XXX.jpg` and `XXX (1).jpg`. I want to use the output of this script as an argument to a command, namely `ql` (quicklook) so I can look through all such images (to verify they are indeed duplicate images, or just filenames). For instance, I can do `ql *(*' which will allow me to look through all the files 'XXX (1).jpg'; but I want to include in that list also the original 'XXX.jpg' files.

Here is my script so far:

```
dups=()
for file in *\(*; do
    dups+=( "${file}" )

    breakdown=( $file )
    dupfile="${breakdown[0]}.jpg"
    if [ -e "$dupfile" ]; then
        dups+=( "$dupfile" )
    fi
done

echo ${dups[@]}
```

As far as building an array of the required filenames goes, it works. But when it comes to invoking something like `ql $(./printdups.sh)`, the command gets confused by the filenames with spaces. It will attempt to open 'XXX' as a file, and then '(1).jpg' as another file. So the question is, **how can I echo this array such that filenames with spaces are recognised as such by the command I pass it to?**

I have tried changing line 3 to:

```
dups+=( "'$file'" )
```

And:

```
dups+=( "${file/ /\ }" )
```

Both to no avail.

Comment: So duplicates are `XXX.ext` and `XXX (1).ext` and `XXX (<any number>).ext` ?

Comment: In my use case, it's unlikely there will be any more duplicates beyond `XXX (1).ext` so I don't really care if the solution extends to more

Comment: Basically, my script as I've quoted it does everything I want it to as far as building the array goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass arrays from one process to another. All you are doing is writing a space-separated sequence of file names to standard output, and the unquoted command substitution in `ql $(./printdups.sh)` fails for the same reason you need an array in the first place: word-splitting does not distinguish between spaces *in* file names and spaces *between* file names.

I would recommend defining a *function*, rather than a script, and have that function populate a global array that you can access directly after the function has been called.

```
get_dups () {
  dups=()
  for file in *\(*; do
    dups+=( "$file" )
    read -a breakdown <<< "$file"  # safer way to split the name into parts
    dupfile="${breakdown[0]}.jpg"
    if [ -e "$dupfile" ]; then
      dups+=( "$dupfile" )
    fi
  done
}

get_dups
ql "${dups[@]}"
```

Comment: Ah, thanks - that seems obvious now that I look at it. I am still confused as to why that works but there is no equivalent technique to achieve the same thing by piping or otherwise channeling output to its arguments. Isn't everything ultimately a string in Bash? If `"${dups[@]}"` results in a string passed to `ql`, why does this have a special status that can't be constructed by less direct means? Moreover, why didn't my attempted solutions work when I can successfully type both `ql 'XXX (1).ext' XXX.ext` and `ql XXX\ (1).ext XXX.ext`?

Comment: Hang on - I just tried it and `ql` only opens the first file in the array. I'm afraid your solution doesn't work.

Comment: My current solution is to _delete_ line 3 from my script, and run `ql *\(* $(./printdups.sh)`. But when I try and incorporate this line into the script itself as `ql *\(* ${dups[@]}` I get the same effect: it only opens the first file in the list. I find this highly mysterious...

Comment: The string is the only data type, but that doesn't mean everything is a *single* string. The `@` index behaves specially; `"${dups[@]}"` expands to a sequence of separate words, one for each element of the array. This is so you can preserve whitespace in those elements without being interpreted as a separator in the expansion.

Comment: That is, given `x=("a b" "c d")`, `"${x[@]}"` (the quotes are necessary!) is equivalent to `"a b" "c d"`, not `"a b c d"` (which would be the result of `"${x[*]}"`) or `a b c d`(the result of either expansion if left unquoted).

Comment: Ah thanks, yes, that makes sense; and I understand why passing the result of that expression to `echo` would erase that difference, since it will just concatenate all the strings it's given.

Could you explain why doing `ql "${dups[@]}"` inside my script doesn't work?

Comment: You aren't setting `dups` correctly. It's just `dups+=("$file")`. You don't need to manually add extra quotes or escape whitespace; quoting `$file` alone ensures that the exact value as needed is added to the array.

Comment: I _am_ doing `dups+=("$file")` (well ok I was doing `("${file}")`, which was an artefact of having tried the escaping whitespace solution before, but I've changed it back now). Those other versions of the same line I quoted were examples of attempts I made. Changing the line to `dups+=("$file")` doesn't change the fact that `ql "${dups[@]}"` doesn't work as expected...